# Change the Secure.java class of the play framework

Tags: security, playframework

Is it advisable to make changes in the methods of the Secure class of play framework?
Or is there a way around it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by changing it? If it is implementing the security provided by the secure module, then you simply need to extend it.

Comment: I want to show my own login-page. So I've added a render("@Application.login"); to the Secure-class login()-method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Secure.class` **no**. `Security.class` **yes**.

To make changes to the Secure.class. No, normally, it should be ok in most cases. But, you will have to extend `Security` class. There are several methods in this class that have to be overridden to fit your application.

```
static boolean authenticate(String username, String password);
static boolean check(String profile);
static String connected();
static void onAuthenticated();
static void onDisconnect();
static void onDisconnected();
```

**EDIT :** 
After reading all the comments and understanding Joe's real need, here is part of the solution.

1. Create a normal login page. You can do this by adding the secure dependency in your `dependencies.yml` file. (Also run `play dependencies`)
2. Extends `Security` for overriding of authenticate method.
3. Also override `onAuthenticate` method to redirect toward the page of yuor choice using `redirect()`
4. Create a new tag `loginbox.html` in `tags` folder. Code is pasted below.
5. Use loginbox tag in your homepage : `#{loginbox /}`

That means :

- You will have a login box on homepage.
- When users login authenticate, they will be redirected to the page of your choice.
- When users login fails, they will be redirected toward the login page and will see errors there.

### loginbox.html

```
#{form @authenticate()}
    <label>Login</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="80"/>

    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="80"/>

    <input type="submit" class="rounded" value="Se connecter" />
#{/form}
```

Comment: ok, but how can i redirect to a other page as default after the login?

Comment: By overriding onAuthenticated method. Plus by default, it is redirecting your to last visited page or `/`.

Comment: Hmm.. good question. I'd do something with the @Before advice - notice it's an unlogged session in the request, then in index() check whether it was unlogged first, logged in now, and redirect. But I'm away from my desk and thus documentation, might be simpler :)

Comment: so i can simply write redirect(url) in the ovirrided onAuthenicated()-method ?

Comment: And is there a way to redirect to another page, if the user enters the wrong password or username?

Comment: I really cannot understand why you would possibly want to do this. Autentification is simple. Login succes -> goto last visited page or /. Login failure goto login page. If for any possible you don't have this pattern, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: The first problem is that i have a login box on my home-page. (Not a own login site). After the login the user should be redirected to the members-area - otherwhise he should come back to the home-page (with the login-box) and see what's wrong (wrong username,..)

Comment: And as I said, that is IMHO not the way to do it. If the user is trying to login and something went wrong, he is not interested in reloading home page. He wants to know what went wrong, not read your homepage and retry login.

Comment: ok, but i only i want to reload the home page because the login-box is on the home page. And in this loginbox the errors would be listed.

Comment: You shouln't. Create a login component you will include in the home page. And create full login page. In case of error, goto login page. You can display errors there.

Answer (score 5):

Its better to extend the Security class (as Zenklys mentioned) and override the methods you are interested in.
Check this [Play Secure document](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/secure#aCustomizetheauthenticationmechanisma)
Having said that, nothing prevents you from modifying Secure class itself, but you will need to make sure to reflect the changes on every Play upgrade.

UPDATE

If you want to have your own login page, its simple, just create 'Secure' folder in you application view folder and add your verion of 'login.html' in there. i.e you are effectively overriding default Secure module login page.

Answer (score 0):

Although play advises you to extend the Security class (and override the login.html page by issuing the command play secure:override --login) ... I preferred to actually modify the secure module itself because I could not do everything I wanted to by extending it. So, here is an alternative solution that works better for me and gives me less issues in general. I am using play 1.2.4

1. Copy the "secure" module folder from the play framework to your /modules folder (replacing the text file "secure" if there is one)
2. Remove the "require play -> secure" from dependencies.yml
3. Comment out this line in application.conf #module.secure=${play.path}/modules/secure 
   (or change it to module.secure=modules/secure if that doesn't work)
4. $ play dependencies